# Symfony 2 + Nginx : can't load the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm new with Linux, PHP, Nginx & Symfony (yes, this will be a long road :) ) and I'm in trouble with creating a new Symfony project.

**The problem**

I browsed the web and others topics here, but I can't deal with the following message while accessing `app_dev.php` :

`An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)
Do you want to open the profiler?`

And if I click `OK`, I'm redirected on `http://testsite.local/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f63f84` that results in a 404 error.

**The config**

I have a fresh install of Nginx with fpm that works fine with à standard PHP site.

`app.php` and `config.php` both work well (no problems spotted in config.php).

Here is the path of my Symfony project : `/srv/www/testsite.local/public_html/Symfony/`

And here my (basic) config of Nginx (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/testsite.local`):

```
server {
    server_name testsite.local;
    access_log /srv/www/testsite.local/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/testsite.local/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/testsite.local/public_html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea of how to solve this issue, let me know. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you first try official symfony configuration: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Miro & @VEBERArnaud : Thx guys, it works now.
Here is the solution, based on your suggestions :

```
server {
    server_name testsite.local;
    access_log /srv/www/testsite.local/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/testsite.local/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/testsite.local/public_html;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app_dev.php
        try_files $uri /Symfony/web/app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This nginx configuration should work for your dev environment

```
server {
    server_name testsite.local;
    root /srv/www/testsite.local/public_html;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    error_log /srv/www/testsite.local/logs/error.log;
    access_log /srv/www/testsite.local/logs/access.log;
}
```

If it's not check your fastcgi_params (`/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`)

And don't forget to reload your nginx server

--

This configuration is a mix of the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) and the configuration you posted